# Converting offset of datetime in Python 3.6

Tags: python, datetime, boto3

I have researched enough before posting this and I know there are a ton of a similar questions but none of them has a solid or uniform solution and also my case is slightly different.

My case is simple. I have the following value `2019-07-31 12:02:35+00:00` stored in a variable. I want to split the hours part alone out of it. this can be done using "strptime" and I tried the following method `onlytime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateandtime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")` But I was displayed with the following error

> "ValueError: time data '2019-07-31 12:02:35+00:00' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%%z'"

`%z` should be working with pyhton 3.2 and above so that should not be the problem.I also tried date-utils() but the docs were confusing and I couldn't find a way to use them properly here.  So what can be done here to achieve my use case? Below is my entire code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import datetime
inputdata = boto3.client('s3')
details = inputdata.list_objects_v2(Bucket='testbucket')
for timedetails in details['Contents']:
    dateandtime = timedetails['LastModified']
    onlytime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateandtime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
    print (onlytime)
```

**UPDATE:** The same program is working in online compilers when I execute the datetime part alone. So I'm adding some more details about the input JSON: This is the JSON stored in the variable `details`

```
{
'Contents': [{
        u 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 12, 2, 35, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
        u 'ETag': '"1a8f23054d922eff88a644bd003e6397"',
        u 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD',
        u 'Key': u 'EVNET- task & window.docx',
        u 'Size': 783570
    }
}
```

However when I print the value stored in `dateandtime` it is displayed as `2019-07-31 12:02:35+00:00`. I'm not sure whether these details could mean something but.

Comment: You have an extra `%` for the timezone (`%%z` instead of `%z`) . Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: @akshayk No luck Akshay. Just now tried, I'm gonna edit the question to remove that extra `%`

Comment: Strange. Are you getting the same error ? It seems to be working when I try it [link](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousDecimalNotification)

Comment: @akshayk yes still the same error. But it is working fine in the link you provided. Give me moment let me add some more detail about the Json to the question

Comment: @akshayk Updated the question

Comment: @akshayk This functionality was added in 3.7. Try doing the same in 3.6

Comment: @KurtisStreutker- Ah okay. That explains it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed in version 3.7: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, '+01:00:00' will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'.

it seems that python 3.6 only support +0000, no colon

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

how about this:

```
import datetime
import re
regex = r"([+-])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})"
subst = "\\1\\2\\3"
dateandtime = "2019-07-31 12:02:35+00:00"
dateandtime = re.sub(regex, subst, dateandtime, 0)
print(dateandtime)
onlytime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateandtime),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
print(onlytime)
```

Comment: Great effort! Now I have one final doubt. the program is working fine but what exactly is the line `regex = r"([+-])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})"` and `subst = "\\1\\2\\3"` is doing here. Is there any reference link to understand the concept?

Comment: I have figured out about `regex = r....` part. Can you just explain about the `subst = "\\1\\2\\3"` part and how the replacements work?

Comment: +00:00 will match the regular expression as  (+)(00):(00), " \1"  represent  the  first  group "+",  "\2"  represent "00", "\3" represent "00" , so "\1\2\3"  represent  "+0000", the  re.sub function will replace  'regex'  with  'subst',  so  it will teplace  +00:00  with  +0000.   you can search "Regular Expression  Named Groups and Backreferences"

Comment: You can use a raw string to avoid the extra backslashes `subst = r"\1\2\3"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is UTC offsets. The RFC 3339 Internet Date/Time Format requires that every date-time includes a UTC offset, and that those offsets can either be Z (short for "Zulu time") or in +HH:MM or -HH:MM format, like +05:00 or -10:30.

Consequently, these are all valid RFC 3339 datetimes:

```
2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z
2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686+05:00
2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686-10:30
```

Alas, the format strings used by strptime and strftime have no directive that corresponds to UTC offsets in RFC 3339 format. You need to use a third party library or parse without the offset.

[Helpful link](https://medium.com/@pritishmishra_72667/converting-rfc3339-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-python-8dfa485358ff)